# cshtml failed to build in production (vsts)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-pipelines, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using Aspnetboilerplate framework in my Web project.

Everything was working until I noticed that my production environment was very slow on first page access.

Doing some researchs I discovered that the problem was to not pre compile cshtml views on build. So, in my vsts build definition I added the follow:

> /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:UseMerge=true /p:SingleAssemblyName=AppCode

But now I'm getting the follow error on all my cshtml views:

> Seduca.Web\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\App\Main\views\aulas\index.cshtml(5,0): Error CS0103: The name 'IsGranted' does not exist in the current context

Works if I put this on top of each view:

```
@inherits Seduca.Web.Views.SeducaWebViewPageBase
```

but it looks like my file (web.config) is being ignored.

My .csproj looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
    <LangVersion>6</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ExtraWebConfigs Include="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\**\web.config" />
      <ExtraPackageTmp Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(&quot;$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)&quot;, &quot;PackageTmp&quot;, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(ExtraWebConfigs)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(ExtraPackageTmp)" />
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
```

And the web.config:
[image]

The error only happens in vsts build. In local deploy, (with release option and precompile) it works.

I've tried with hosted and private agents on vsts.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, can you share the sample project on the OneDrive?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on local visual studio. If I put the options to precompile and merge I get the same error. But if I manually delete bin and obj folders and try again it works. Could vsts be keeping any kind of cache?

Comment: Do you use private agent? If so, 1. Select Get Sources 2. Choose true in Clean dropdown box

Comment: I`m using hosted agent. I tried this now, got the same error =/

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Comment: I downloaded the aspnetboilerplate template again and deployed it to vsts with the precompile and merge options, it worked.  I did compare all web.config files and didn't see any difference. I don't know what to looking for.

Comment: You need the namespace of any class that you reference in the web.config. Add '<add namespace="Seduca.Web.Views"/>'

Comment: @Wurd, still getting the error.

Comment: Do you use the same build definition (Just change the source mapping)? Can you share the logs of these builds on the OneDrive? We will compare them.

Comment: Another option you have is to import namespaces programmatically through your Global.asax, for example `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebCodeRazorHost.AddGlobalImport("Namespace.Namespace");`

Answer (score -1):

The issue appears to be that you are not adding the namespaces to the correct `Web.config` file. `.cshtml` files get their globally imported namespaces from the `Views\Web.config` file, not the root `Web.config` file.

The information you have in the root `Web.config` file is correct, you just need to move it to the `Views\Web.config` file.

Comment: The two files are exactly the same (App/Main/web.config and Views/web.config). And both have the namespaces (you can see on screenshot). But thank you for try to help.